# why igneous phosphate rocks contain less uranium than sedimentary rocks?

Tags: geology, geochemistry

Sedimentary rock phosphates contain much higher concentrations of potentially hazardous elements (As, Cd, Cr,Pb, Se and U)than igneous rock phosphates. Why?
Is it because U concentration in magmatic water is lower than in ocean water?
how could U accomodate in the apatite of igneous?

Comment: I found this [mining oriented description of how U becomes concentrated.](http://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/energy/province-sedimentary-basin-geology/uranium-thorium-geology)

Comment: Interesting question. By the way, some magmatic apatites have lots of thorium, whereas there is almost no thorium in sedimentary apatites.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and information. Very apprecited for that. One possible reason could be U become enriched in marine sedimentary by reworking after precipitation, in constract, igneous does not have that process.